# Conservative IDisposable marking on interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, idisposable

In a situation where implementations of an interface may *or may not* need to be disposed of, is it a good idea to require that *all* implementations must be disposed of by **marking the interface itself as `IDisposable`**?

This forces users of this interface to always dispose of the objects even though it might be unnecessary for certain implementations.  The goal is obviously to **ensure** that implementations are always **seamlessly swappable**.  The alternative is to leave it to the user to decide, which might seem more correct, but more difficult to communicate.  On the other hand, considering a user that only has a symbol declared with the type of the interface, it might seem more correct to require that it be disposed of unconditionally.  Is there a trade-off or a fallacy in this reasoning?

If the question is too dependent on the situation, I'd like to frame it in the context of textbook repositories (of the repository design pattern), where *most* known implementations will need to be disposed of.

Comment: When you quote something, a link to the source is usually helpful.

Comment: This question is too broad, and depends on the specific implementation detail. I suggest you either specify a use case and post some code, or it will be difficult to answer this question properly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I haven't quoted anything.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, I assume most people know about the repository pattern, should I really expand on it?

Comment: The formatting (now removed) suggested you did.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, sorry, I intended to de-emphasize the rationale; Athari helpfully edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the question is too dependent on the situation, I'd like to frame it in the context of textbook repositories (of the repository design pattern), where most known implementations will need to be disposed of.

If you are writing library code that instantiates objects and is responsible for their lifetime, then the *ideal* scenario would be to *handle* `IDisposable`, but not to *demand* it unless it is *overwhelmingly* likely that most implementations will require cleanup; for example by using `is` or `as` at the point when your code is done with the unknown object. It is rarely as simple as this but for example:

```
IFoo obj = (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(unknownType);
using(obj as IDisposable)
{
    // TODO: code
}
```

Comment: I like this, it does indeed seem like the best-of-both-worlds solution; though unfortunately not as pretty as it requires additional logic at every call site on the user-side.  I suspect *not* using `using` might be easier; instead only casting and calling manually at the end of the site: `var obj as IDisposable; if (obj != null) obj.Dispose();`.  It should be possible to introduce an abstract base type to do this more nicely, but that sounds rather overkill.

Comment: @tne in most interesting cases, creation and disposal are separated from eachother *anyway*, so the question of `using` becomes moot. The nice thing, though, is that it handles exceptions. To be equivalent, you'd need to add `try`/`finally`.

Comment: Indeed.  For completeness, I'll also add to your answer that the technique is not only useful for library code, but also for application code which use some form of dependency injection or are otherwise prevented to know about the actual implementation of the interfaces they use.

Comment: Use of `as IDisposable` generally indicates that the previous type of the variable *should* have implemented `IDisposable` in the first place (e.g. `IEnumerable` should have implemented it, the way `IEnumerable<T>` does).  Even if only 1% of the classes that are actually used require cleanup, having all classes of objects certain pieces of client code may acquire implement `IDisposable`, and having those pieces of client code call `Dispose` on every item, is apt to be more efficient than requiring that those pieces of client code check whether the objects they receive implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 2):

In deciding whether `IFoo` should implement `IDisposable`, the critical question shouldn't be whether a substantial fraction of types implementing `IFoo` will need disposal, or even whether a substantial fraction of the object instances implementing `IFoo` will need disposal, but rather whether it's likely that any non-trivial fraction of the instances *which are returned by a factory method whose return type is `IFoo`* will need to be disposed *by the caller of that factory method*.

Consider `IEnumerator`.  Only a tiny fraction of the classes which implement it require disposal (the fraction probably increased significantly with the introduction of iterators), but the vast majority of instances will be obtained by a call to factory method `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`, whose return type is `IEnumerator`.  Code which calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` will often have no knowledge of whether the returned object will require disposal or not; for semantic correctness, unless code knows that the types of `IEnumerable` it's using won't return instances that require disposal, it must for correctness try-cast the returned implements to `IDisposable` and, if the result is non-null, dispose them.

When Microsoft implemented `IEnumerator<T>`, they realized that the burden of consumers having to try-cast enumerators to `IDisposable` was far greater than would be the burden of implementers having to implement a do-nothing `Dispose` method.  Semantic correctness requires that consumers call `Dispose` on any enumerator which implements `IDisposable`, and unconditionally calling a do-nothing `Dispose` method on a type which is known to implement it is easier and faster than testing whether a type which might implement `IDisposable`, does so.

Even if only 1% of `IEnumerator<T>` implementations implement `IDisposable`, the vast majority of consumers must, for semantic correctness, assume that *any* of them *might*.  Having `IEnumerable<T>` inherit `IDisposable` does not impart any obligation on consumers that they wouldn't otherwise have--it just makes it easier for them to carry out obligations *that they would have in any case*.

Comment: Too bad there's no static hint you can place on a specific GetEnumerator() that says no you don't need to dispose this.

Comment: @Joshua: Or in some cases even a means of run-time checking.  In many cases disposing something unconditionally is cheaper than checking if disposal will be required, but in some cases, especially those involving wrapped objects, keeping a reference to an object around for the purpose of disposing it may add extra complexity that would not otherwise be needed.

Comment: Which is why I was talking about a static check so the compiler doesn't generate the call.

Comment: @Joshua: Even in cases where it couldn't be tested statically, being able to know *when the enumerator is created* that it won't be necessary to track its lifetime may still be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are exposing an interface

```
ISomeInterface
```

If you intend to use this interface to trigger the disposal, i.e. you want to call `Dispose`, then, it should implement `IDisposable`.

```
ISomeInterface : IDisposable
```

However, consider  that the composition of the ubiquitous `IDisposable` will certainly cause 3rd-party users of `ISomeInterface` implementations to call `Dispose` themsevles, either explicitly or in `using` blocks.

If you are not intending to call `Dispose` yourself, leave the choice to the concrete class implementer. They alone can decide if disposal will be necessary in a given situation.

---

Now I can [quote an authoritative source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565531/659190),

> not to demand it unless it is overwhelmingly likely that most implementations will require cleanup

I would suggest that in the example of a `Stream`  it is "overwhelmingly likely."

Comment: um... I'm pretty sure I don't qualify as an "authoritative source"

Comment: @MarcGravell, I'll give you 489k reasons.

Comment: In any case, there seems to be some unanimous agreement in the answers of this question: "most" and "overwhelmingly likely" are close enough for me.  If such a condition does *not* apply and forcing unconditional disposal is not a good idea, then the question of whether to dispose conditionally by casting (as suggested by Marc Gravell) is left open to the user, and this again sounds very reasonable.  If a user decides against it, then they consciously accept that they may not use *any* implementation.  Thank you all for the helpful insight.

Comment: @tne: If the the type will be used as the return type for factory methods which *transfer ownership to their callers*, and *any* instances will need disposal, it should implement `IDisposable`.  If all instances which require disposal will be known by their owners by types more specific than your interface, type, then the interface doesn't require `IDisposable` even if 90% of implementations do.

Comment: @supercat: I think it's one of those things where there is unfortunately no such ultimate rule. There are legitimate cases where you don't want to require implementers of the interface to provide dummy `Dispose` no-ops because *some* will have a real one. Even with an intermediary base type, you'd need to document a contract that forbids users to use the IF type directly, which is not much different than documenting that the user is responsible for checking if the type is disposable and for disposing it if it is.

Comment: @tne: If a factory method will sometimes return things that require the recipient to call `Dispose`, life will almost always be easier for the consumer if it can unconditionally call `Dispose` than if it has to first test for `IDisposable`.  Further, in cases where recipients might benefit from knowing whether `Dispose` is really necessary (e.g. for the rare case of objects like encapsulating a sharable view of an immutable resource), that could best be handled by having the object's interface include a `RequiresDispose` property, since it would be entirely possible...

Comment: ...for some instances of a type to hold resources that require cleanup, but for other instances *of the same type* to not require cleanup [e.g. a type which represents an immutable sound might stream from disk file if a file is large, or load the entire sound into memory and close the file if it's small].  If a caller could make optimizations based upon whether an object actually required cleanup, having a method to ask whether an instance might require cleanup would be more efficient and more accurate than basing the determination upon type alone.

Comment: @supercat: I agree, a method definitely communicates it better than an obscure requirement to check for the type in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Having recently pondered on the issue again, I would like to share another guideline / rule of thumb that, if applicable, may make the decision easier.

What nobody considered yet is the ratio of users / implementations:

- If there are more users than implementations, and especially if the implementations are all under your control, then *consider* marking the interface `IDisposable` and force the users to always dispose even if it's not strictly necessary. As long as this feels appropriate for the use-case at hand, it will *most likely* make the life of the users simpler: they won't need to check if they need to dispose or not, they'll do it systematically. The drawback is that you will have to implement dummy `Dispose` methods for those implementations that don't require it. Unless you have peculiar performance requirements, this call is perfectly fine (I would imagine the only overhead is the virtual table lookup, the method itself is likely optimized-out).
- If there are more implementations than users, for example in the case of a plugin system, then *consider* verifying if the objects implement `IDisposable` dynamically in your core, so that implementations don't ever have to implement dummy `IDisposable` methods. The drawback is that you require additional logic in your core. Overhead is that of a cast & null-check.

**tl;dr:** We often assume there will be more users than implementations. This is not always the case.

Of course, this is just *one* dimension of the problem that you can use to decide; the other dimension is that of the ratio between implementations that need to be disposed of and implementations that don't.  See the other answers for a discussion on this aspect.

Once you've evaluated each, take all considerations at once, salt with your opinion, and make your decision.